# Flip crossing doesn't work in TikZ with two strands

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

I am struggling to change the bottom crossing of this picture. This is for my project and the deadline is in an hour but I've just found out this mistake! Please can someone help to flip that crossing to purple strand on top? I have tried using combinations in  flip crossing/.list={} but none of them seem to work. This is urgent and any help would be grateful!!

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amstext,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{braids}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,hobby,knots,celtic,shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2,use Hobby shortcut, add arrow/.style={postaction={decorate}, decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow[line width=4pt]{>}}}}]
\begin{knot}[
  clip width=5, consider self intersections=true,
  ignore endpoint intersections=false,
  flip crossing/.list={1,3},
  rotate=180
  ]
\strand [line width=4pt, blue] (1.3,-1)
to [out=up, in=right] (0.7,1)
to [out=left, in=up] (-0.5,0)
to [out=down, in=left] (0,-.5)
[add arrow,blue]
to [out=right, in=down] (0.5,0)
to [out=up, in=down] (0.5,1.5)
to [out=up,in=right] (-1.3,2)
to [out=left, in=down] (-1.85,2.5);
\strand [line width=4pt, violet] (-1.85,-1)
to [out=up, in=left] (-1.2,-0.3)
to [out=right, in=left] (0,-1)
to [out=right, in=down] (0.7,-0.7)
to [out=up, in=right] (0,0)
to [out=left, in=down] (-1.1,1)
to [out=up, in=left] (0.5,1.5)
to [out=right, in=down](1.3,2.5);
\end{knot}
\path (0,-.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really easy if you use `draft mode=crossings` to see which index refers to which crossing (and braids is not needed here).

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz} 
%\usepackage{braids}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,hobby,knots,celtic,shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Strand}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2,use Hobby shortcut, add arrow/.style={postaction={decorate}, decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow[line width=4pt]{>}}}}]
\begin{knot}[%draft mode=crossings,
  clip width=5, consider self intersections=true,
  ignore endpoint intersections=false,
  flip crossing/.list={1,2,3,7},
  rotate=180
  ]
\strand [line width=4pt, blue] (1.3,-1)
to [out=up, in=right] (0.7,1)
to [out=left, in=up] (-0.5,0)
to [out=down, in=left] (0,-.5)
[add arrow,blue]
to [out=right, in=down] (0.5,0)
to [out=up, in=down] (0.5,1.5)
to [out=up,in=right] (-1.3,2)
to [out=left, in=down] (-1.85,2.5);
\strand [line width=4pt, violet] (-1.85,-1)
to [out=up, in=left] (-1.2,-0.3)
to [out=right, in=left] (0,-1)
to [out=right, in=down] (0.7,-0.7)
to [out=up, in=right] (0,0)
to [out=left, in=down] (-1.1,1)
to [out=up, in=left] (0.5,1.5)
to [out=right, in=down](1.3,2.5);
\end{knot}
\path (0,-.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]